# Blank gfci with no light when reset

Tags: electrical, gfci

Located in my bathroom,  this blank gfci is orange when I hit test button, then no light when I hit reset button. There is a spa in the room that works. Is this normal? House was built 2003-4. We recently moved in.

Comment: Lights on GFCIs vary quite a bit, so that sounds plausibly normal. Generally speaking, everything electrical in a bathroom, except (again, generally) overhead lights & fans, should be GFCI protected. Assuming "blank GFCI" means "TEST/RESET buttons but no receptacles", when you hit TEST *something* should turn off - the spa or receptacles or something else.

Comment: What make and model is the GFCI in question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal.  Some brands have a light when on, some brands don't.  Ideally you could find the instructions for that specific model, but it sounds like no cause for concern.